# get most recent IP address from log-in log

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an activity log table on a site. There are columns for date/time, userID and IP address for each log-in.

I want to retrieve a list of unique usernames and the most recent IP address they logged in from.

What's the best way to retrieve this from the table using t-sql on SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A portable approach is:

```
select l.userID, l.Date, l.IpAddress
from (
    select userID, max(Date) as MaxDate
    from Log
    group by userID
) lm
inner join Log l on lm.userID = l.userID
    and lm.MaxDate = l.Date
```

If you have SQL Server 2005+, you can also do:

```
select * from
(
    select userID, Date, IpAddress,  
        Rank() over (Partition BY userID order by Date DESC) as Rank
    from Log
) tmp
where Rank = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing at some column / table names here, and I'm assuming username comes from a table (and you aren't storing the username in the log each time):

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT userID, IPaddress, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
  (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY datetimecolumn DESC)
  FROM dbo.LogTable
)
SELECT u.username, x.IPAddress
FROM x INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS u
ON u.userID = x.userID
WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct(user_name), (select top 1 IP_address from log_table where user_name=LOG.user_name order by log_date desc)
from log_table LOG
```

Comment: I am not sure why this was downvoted. It works. The only difference between this one and RedFilter's answers is that this only returns one row per username when there are multiple rows that fit the criteria (ie, when the same user name logs from two IP addresses at the same time). Since this requirement is not detailed in the question, this is therefore a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: thanks James. It is defined on the question. Unique userName and last IP.

Comment: Diego. No it's not. The OP doesn't specify that it's not possible for the same username to log in from two different IPs simultaneous. So I assume it IS possible. In this case, which one do you choose? It's non-deterministic.

Comment: " the most recent IP" thats why I added "order by log_date desc"